# Java sockets issue with headers

Tags: java, http, proxy

I'm writing a proxy using sockets in Java, and now I'm getting an strange issue with headers (I think that the problem are the headers)...
When I try to send back the URL to the client (in this case the webbrowser), I'm getting this error if I connect to www.google.com:

1. That’s an error. 
   Your client has issued a malformed or illegal request. That’s all we know.

But the strange thing is that there are other webs that are working fine and are not getting any errors...

Any help on this would be much appreciated...

Thanks.

This is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

public class Server {


public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(80);
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private final Socket clientSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            String url = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream(), "ISO-8859-1"));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));




            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
            for (String buffer; (buffer = in.readLine()) != null;) {
            if (buffer.isEmpty()) break;
            builder.append(buffer.replaceAll("keep-alive", "close")+"\r\n");
            if(buffer.contains("Host"))
                {
                //parse the host
                url = buffer.replaceAll("Host: ", "");
                }
            //System.out.println(builder);
            }

   if (url.contains("elotrolado.net")){         

            out.write("HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n");
            out.write("Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT\r\n");
            out.write("Server: Apache/0.8.4\r\n");
            out.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
            out.write("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:59:59 GMT\r\n");
            out.write("Last-modified: Fri, 09 Aug 1996 14:21:40 GMT\r\n");
            out.write("\r\n");
            out.write("<TITLE>DENEGADO</TITLE>");
            out.write("<P>Acceso a "+url+" denegado</P>");
            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();         

   }
   else
   {

            String IP = InetAddress.getByName(url).getHostAddress().toString();                

            //new socket to send the information over

            Socket ss = new Socket(url, 80);
            //printwriter to send text over the output stream
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(ss.getOutputStream()); 

            //send the request from the client
            String req = builder.toString();
            System.out.println(req);
            String reqq=URLEncoder.encode(req, "UTF-8");
            pw.println(reqq);
            pw.flush();

            //create inputstream to receive the web page from the host
            BufferedInputStream inn = new BufferedInputStream(ss.getInputStream());

            //create outputstream to send the web page to the client
            BufferedOutputStream outt = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytesread;

            //send the response back to the client
            while((bytesread = inn.read(bytebuffer)) != -1) {
            outt.write(bytebuffer,0, bytesread);
            outt.flush();
            }

            ss.close();
            pw.close();
            outt.close();
            inn.close();
            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(RuntimeException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: JavaScript has nothing to do with this question.

Comment: Duplicate of your [Issue getting the images with sockets](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20028956/issue-getting-the-images-with-sockets)