# Issue getting the images with sockets

Tags: java

I'm writing a proxy server using sockets, now it seems that it's "working" more or less but the problem I'm experiencing now is that the images of the URL's are not getting back to the browser, only the text is returned...

This is the code:

```
//create inputstream to receive the web page from the host
BufferedInputStream inn = new    BufferedInputStream(clientURLSocket.getInputStream());
//create outputstream to send the web page to the client
BufferedOutputStream outt = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
URL u = new URL("http://"+url);
ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
try {
   byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
   int bytesRead;
   InputStream stream = u.openStream();
   while ((bytesRead = stream.read(chunk)) > 0) {
      outputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
   }
} catch (IOException e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
outt.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
outt.flush();
```

Maybe ByteArrayOutputStream is not good to receive images?

**Edit (sorry for the late response):**

This is my new code:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.concurrent.*;

public class Server {


public void startServer() {
    final ExecutorService clientProcessingPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);

    Runnable serverTask = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
                @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(8080);
                while (true) {
                    Socket clientSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    Socket clientURLSocket = serverSocket.accept();
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientSocket));
                    clientProcessingPool.submit(new ClientTask(clientURLSocket));
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Thread serverThread = new Thread(serverTask);
    serverThread.start();

}

private class ClientTask implements Runnable {
    private Socket clientSocket;
    private Socket clientURLSocket;

    private ClientTask(Socket clientSocket) {
        this.clientSocket = clientSocket;
        this.clientURLSocket = clientSocket;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        try {

            String url = null;
            String curl = null;
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream()));


            String buffer;
            while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                //System.out.println(buffer);
                if(buffer.contains("GET"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    curl = splitText[1];
                    System.out.println(curl);
                    }
                if(buffer.contains("Host"))
                    {
                    //parse the host
                    url = buffer.replace("Host: ", "");
                    System.out.println(url);
                    }

                if (buffer.isEmpty()) break;
                }

            //String IP = InetAddress.getByName(url).getHostAddress().toString();                

            //new socket to send the information over

            clientURLSocket = new Socket(url, 80);

          //get data from a URL

        /*    URL host = new URL("http://"+url);

            URLConnection urlConnection = host.openConnection();
            InputStream input = urlConnection.getInputStream();

            int data = input.read();
            while(data != -1){
                System.out.print((char) data);
                data = input.read();
            }
            input.close();*/


            //create inputstream to receive the web page from the host
            BufferedInputStream inn = new BufferedInputStream(clientURLSocket.getInputStream());
            //create outputstream to send the web page to the client
            BufferedOutputStream outt = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                URL u = new URL(curl);
                HttpURLConnection connection = null;
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                connection.connect();
                //ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

                try {
                    byte[] chunk = new byte[1024];
                    int bytesRead;
                    InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                    while ((bytesRead = stream.read(chunk)) > 0) {
                        //outputStream.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                        outt.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);
                        outt.flush();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //outt.write(outputStream.toByteArray());
                //outt.flush();


            outt.close();
            inn.close();
            clientURLSocket.close();
          /*  
            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();

   */
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }
    }
}
```

}

Now the problem is that google.com is working fine (it shows all the images and text), but for example youtube.com is not working fine (it also shows the text and images but the web is not being showed completely and it's disordered).

What I'm missing in this code?

By the way, thanks EJP & JB Nizet for your help!

Comment: You don't need the ByteArrayOutputStream at all. Just read from the input socket and write to the output socket. All you're accomplishing with the ByteArrayOutputStream is adding unwanted latency.

Comment: Hi EJP, thanks for your answer but I'm still experiencing the same issue, I have deleted ByteArrayOutputStream and now I'm writing directly on the BufferedOutputStream:  outt.write(chunk, 0, bytesRead);

Comment: What exactly *is* the issue? Are you sure the image retrievals are even going through this code?

Comment: Hi, the issue is that when I connect to google.com (for example) I only get the text, but not getting the google logo (the image). The problem is that I don't know what I'm doing wrong...

Comment: Can you answer my *question* please? "Are you sure the image retrievals are even going through this code?" And here's another one: are you implementing the `HTTP CONNECT` command? and are you telling the client about the existence of this HTTP proxy in the normal way?

Comment: Hi, for the first question: As per JB Nizet answer I think that no. second question: No, this command is not implemented. For the third: The browser is already configured to use a proxy server in localhost so I think that I can answer yes.

Comment: If you haven't implemented the CONNECT command, you must answer 'no'. You haven't implemented an HTTP proxy at all. Look it up. When you configure an HTTP proxy that's what gets sent to it.

Comment: Please see the new code I have posted, now I'm getting another error.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you don't understand how HTTP and HTML work.

When you go to http://google.com with your browser, a first request is sent to get the HTML page. The server response contains the HTML markup, and only that. Then the browser reads and parses this HTML markup and sees that it contains (for example)

```
<img src="logo.png"/>
```

So it sends a new HTTP request to the URL http://google.com/logo.png. The server sends a response containing the bytes of the logo image.

If your code only sends a single request to http://google.com, you'll never get the logo.

Comment: So, I have to send several requests to the URL? How can I do this? What procedure I have to follow?

Comment: You have to send a request to the URL of each resource you want to retrieve. If you want the page, send a request to the URL of the page. If you want the logo, send a request to the URL of the logo. If you can do it for one URL, you should be able to do it for 2 10 or 10000.

Comment: Please see the new code I have posted, now I'm getting another error.

Answer (score 0):

An HTTP proxy is a lot simpler than what you're doing here.

You are supposed to connect to the URL named in the CONNECT command. Not parse the GET and HOST headers. Once you've processed the CONNECT command, the rest is just copying bytes back and forth.